# Strdup is generating core dump?

Tags: c, malloc

I have an application which is written  in C. There I am using `strdup` to copy char*. Before calling strdup even **I am verifying source string. It's not equal to NULL, even though strdup is dumping core.**

**here is the back trace**

```
#0  0x0000005564517bb0 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000556451c4bc in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000005564552b48 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000556455f024 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000005564562ea4 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000005564565638 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000005564569748 in strdup () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000120009804 in read_filesystem_list ()   
#8  0x000000012000a7d0 in monitor_disk ()
#9  0x0000005564213660 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
 ---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#10 0x00000055645ce5dc in __thread_start () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Can any one help me to understand why the strdup is dumping core?

```
struct abc *read_filesystem_list () 
{
struct abc *me =NULL;
struct abc *list =NULL;
struct abc *temp =NULL;
FILE *fp;
fp = setmntent (table, "r");
while ((mnt = getmntent (fp)))
{
 me = (struct abc *) malloc (sizeof (struct abc));
 if(me)
 {
  memset(me, 0, sizeof(struct abc)); 
  if ( mnt->mnt_dir != NULL && mnt->mnt_fsname !=NULL && org_devname!= NULL&& mnt->mnt_type != NULL )
  {
   me->devname = strdup (mnt->mnt_fsname);
   me->org_devname = strdup(org_devname);
   me->mp = strdup (mnt->mnt_dir);
   me->type = strdup (mnt->mnt_type);
  }       
  if(temp) {
  temp->next = me;
  temp = me;
  }
  else {  
  list=temp=me;
  }
  }       
  }
  return list;
  }
```

Comment: The error is on line 42. (Oh, in what file? I haven't a clue--might help if you showed us some of the code).

Comment: I'd say the setup for whatever you're passing to `strdup` in your `read_filesystem_list` is the likely culprit. And non-null isn't enough; it also has to be a properly terminated to be a proper C-string. That's it. Got nothing else.

Comment: `NULL` is not the only invalid value you can pass `strdup()`.  pointers to non NUL terminated strings, uninitialized pointers, pointers to `free`d memory blocks, computed pointers that fall outside object boundaries all invoke undefined behaviour when passed to `strdup`, and may cause crashes. Use the debugger, valgrind or post the source code for `read_filesystem_list ` for us to look at.

Comment: Thank you for reply.Here is my code

Comment: Please post the source code for the full function, along with type definitions.

Comment: `me = (struct abc *) malloc (sizeof (struct abc));
 if(!me)` This conditional is backward.

Comment: As a general piece of advice, this particular failure mode (an abort deep in the guts of `malloc`) is likely to mean that memory got corrupted at some point *before* the current invocation of `malloc` or `strdup` or whatever.

Comment: zwol is right: the code posted is not the code you run.

Answer (score 1):

You duplicate strings that may be `NULL`:

```
if ( mnt->mnt_dir != NULL || mnt->mnt_fsname != NULL )
{   
me->devname = strdup (mnt->mnt_fsname);
me->org_devname = strdup(org_devname);
me->mp = strdup (mnt->mnt_dir);
me->type = strdup (mnt->mnt_type);
}   
}
```

Your test is incorrect and incomplete.  This will work better:

```
if (mnt->mnt_fsname) me->devname = strdup(mnt->mnt_fsname);
if (org_devname)     me->org_devname = strdup(org_devname);
if (mnt->mnt_dir)    me->mp = strdup(mnt->mnt_dir);
if (mnt->mnt_type)   me->type = strdup(mnt->mnt_type);
```

You can also write a utility function that duplicates strings and accepts `NULL` pointers.

Comment: I have tried with by checking all (NULL or not), now also its dumping.All string are not NULL.Is any other way can we check is string is profer or not.

Comment: No, you cannot check pointer validity in the general case. Post the code for `getmntent()` and `setmntent()`

Comment: tthose are all system calls